# Can't install Windows 11: missing drivers

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-11

I currently have no operating system on my PC, and I'm trying to install Windows 11. When It start the installation, It gives me "missing driver" error. So I downloaded the drivers for my motherboard (Gigabyte B360M D2V), but It says that It can't install It.

PS: I'm using a usb with Windows 11 iso on it (flashed using Balena Etcher from another computer with Ubuntu).

Someone can help me? Thank you in advance and sorry for bad english!

Comment: Please add more information about which driver(s) you used and how did you add them to the installation media.

Comment: Has your system got TPM 2?   UEFI and Secure Boot are not drivers, so post what drivers you think you need.

Comment: Note:  A driver EXE or ZIP file is of no value to windows.  You need to extract the contents of these files into separate folders.  Windows is looking for INF files to help it install a driver.

Comment: Your issue is an NTFS formatted partition for the install media, reformat it as FAT32 and extract the ISO to it _(if it's MBR, ensure the partition is marked `Active`)_. I'm unsure why the motherboard's firmware's NTFS driver, or WinPE's NTFS driver, isn't sufficient and could find no information on Microsoft Docs when I ran into the same issue when testing my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1721319/529800) to another question. The ISO should be using an `install.esd` to maintain <4GB file size, but if not, export the `install.wim`'s index to an ESD _(see linked to answer's Step #4)_

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what is stated in the comments, as far as I understand your question, I can offer a solution to try - if necessary - until the question is clear.

During the development of Windows,
We know that "Windows Vista" drivers are available in "Windows 7-8". In my research on "can you use Win 10 drivers with Windows 11" on Google, I came across headlines confirming this.

In this context, my suggestion is:

Install windows 10 on your device, hopefully without having to activate it. After installing the necessary drivers - or after downloading the drivers with windows update (I'm not sure if this part requires activation) -,

Drivers on the system you installed
`dism /online /export-driver/destination:<path>`
Export it to an external disk with the command,

After installing Windows 11, all ! For marked devices, install it by pointing to the external disk directory you selected in the previous step, by saying browse for folders.

Ps. I don't know if there is a legal requirement to state that Windows is a commercial product of Microsoft Corporation.