# Computer always brings up a blue screen at the same time

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I currently have a problem with two computers in the company that I can no longer solve. The computers regularly produce a blue screen, one every week on Tuesday at 09:15, the other every month on Friday at 08:16. And this happens reliably, it is very rare that the blue screen does not occur.

I get the following error in the minidump file:

```
Bugcheck code: 0x3B(0xC0000005, 0xFFFFF805330410ED, 0xFFFFA10D06A8E620, 0x0)
Bugcheck name: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
Driver or module in which error occurred: pmem64.sys (pmem64+0x10ED)
```

Unfortunately I can't find anything about pmem64. Do you have any idea what this could be? Lenovo itself has no idea either.

**Specifications:**

- Hardware: Lenovo ThinkStation P520C (out of 24 units in the company, these are the only two that have the problem)
- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise, one with 2004, the other with 22H2

Comment: check your task scheduler for something running at those times

Comment: @essjae there are no tasks running at that time

Comment: @John Pinnacle Dazzle Software isn't installed (that would be the driver emScan64.sys). The only other ting I can find is "IBM Dynamic System Analysis" but that isn't installed either

Comment: Have you tried to simply reimage these devices? Why are you running unsupported versions of Windows 10?

Comment: I try to avoid reinstalling Windows, as both machines are in continuous use and the software running on them takes at least 2 days to be fully installed and set up again. But I already suspected that this would be the case

Comment: @saltemohn Have you considered configuring a ZTI [Task Sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9l5c.png) via [MDT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=54259) for deploying Windows to machines _(unless the company already has a Microsoft MEM subscription)_? A [ZTI](https://superuser.com/a/1721319/529800) automates everything, from installing Windows, drivers, and software, and there are a myriad of guides that go into more detail than my linked answer. MDT has a minor learning curve, but once setup, updating the ZTI and deploying Windows takes hours, instead of days

Comment: Since the likely source of that file **is** https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-dynamic-system-analysis-dsa, could it be that a check is run on those PC's remotely?