How does Windows construct and create the initial name of the PC?
When you setup your PC for the very first time, Windows have automatically created a name for the PC. Most people don't care and don't bother to change it. However, it would be interesting to know how that string is constructed, especially as it doesn't look random.
For example, on one lap top is named: LAPTOP-FJNTRVPC.

How does windows know/determine it's a LAPTOP?
How does the remainder of the string (FJNTRVPC) get constructed?

Unfortunately the following similar questions and references did not yield a clear answer, as they provide contradicted or possibly outdated answers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-computername
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-systemenclosure
How are Dell's default computer names (DESKTOP-XXXXXX) generated?


This might be helpful (https://superuser.com/questions/1624231/how-to-create-an-unattended-windows-installation-medium-iso-usb-supporting-secur/1721319#1721319). Around "ComputerName:  | OEMName:  | ProductKey: " . This is part of story, but might give you a hint(s).

so can you help us understand how this article doesn't answer your question? Cause it totally does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-computername

Its because the people who made your laptop installed windows using a predefined set of configuration arguments. manufacturers who assemble and sell computers are called OEMs (Original Equipment Manufacturers), and the windows installer lets those OEMs customize the setup experience by feeding it preconfigured data, as well as allow them install windows in a fully automated fashion at manufacturing-scale.
This article from your question states clearly how the name is generated if the OEM does not supply a ComputerName argument in the unattend.xml file their installer uses. To get more details on the exact arguments used, you will have to inspect that file.
From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-computername

ComputerName specifies the computer name used to access the computer from the network.
Note   In Windows 10, users can no longer enter a computer name during
OOBE as the name is auto-generated. To set a default computer name
pre-OOBE, OEMs can configure ComputerName in the Unattend.xml file and
specify a name for the computer. After OOBE, end users can change this
default computer name after OOBE by changing it in the System
Properties page. Values
If ComputerName is not specified, a random computer name is generated.
If ComputerName set to an asterisk (*) or is included but empty (""),
Windows creates a random 15-character name using up to 7 characters
from FullName and Organization, then a dash, then more random
characters.


I'm particularity interested to know how the random string is generated. (I'm not convinced it's random.) However, I'm not sure if this code is openly available somewhere?

I don't recall which rule of computer science it was, but its less than #10; a digital system can never generate a truly random number. Quantum systems probably can, but in terms of standard PCs, you are right, no RNG is truly random, and many RNGs are at least semi-deterministic. that said, why is this of concern to you? Some windows code is available out there, but windows is not opensource, and most of the OS code has never been officially published for legal consumption.

No that's not what I meant. I meant that the random part could be based on some HW id or other HW or OS release specific id.
